# Removing X-Frame-Options being added automatically only in Iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, x-frame-options

So we have this application that opens up in an Iframe but the X-Frame-Options is blocking it. I want it to be completely remove from the httpheader. I know it can be blocked by doing the following:

> MVC 5 automatically adds an X-Frame-Options Header, so go to your Global.asax file and add this to the Application_Start() method:

```
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

But my Global.asax is looking different and I can't seem to get it to work somehow. It looks like this:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ApplicationWebInterface.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Any ideas to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add it to Global.asax.cs not Global.asax.